# How do you smelt ore?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've gathered metal ore from a mine, but the forge only uses iron bars to create items.  I can't seem to find an option to convert my ore into bars; do I need a special kind of forge, or I am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What you are looking for is a furnace/smelter, which is typically in the shape of a very large, cone-shaped oven. Not all forges have a smelter, but Whiterun has one.

A list of all smelters can be found on [this](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smelting) site

Comment: where is the furnace in whiterun?

Comment: Right next to Warmaidens, just a few feet past the forge, grindstone et al.

Comment: Would be nice if Wimpey added Jeremy's comment to his answer

Comment: I could, but it is much more convenient if I added the location of all smelters, which is what I did, just now.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Wimpey's Answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35042/how-do-you-smelt-ore/35044#35044), there is another smelter out in the field by [Soljund's Sinkhole](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Soljund%27s_Sinkhole).

Much less accessible than the one in Whiterun, but this is just saying that another one is available.

Comment: [Mind my profile] There are other smelters too!