# Turning Iron Ore into Iron Ingots?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you smelt ore?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35042/how-do-you-smelt-ore)

I have heaps of Iron Ore and I can't use it for anything. So I was wondering how to turn Iron Ore into Iron Ingots so I can use them.

Answer (score 8):

### Smelt them.

Go to the nearest **blacksmith** and go to the Smelter, and then choose Iron Ignot and smelt them. You will get 1 Iron Ignot for every 1 Iron Ore.

[Here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smelting) is a list of Blacksmiths that offer Smelting.

Answer (score 2):

**Transmute them.**

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Transmute_Mineral_Ore

This is a spell that with 4 castings, converts two iron ore into two gold ore, which you can then smelt into one gold ignot, which can be combined with gems to make jewelry, which is the fastest way to level Smithing.